# Shell script - rm does not remove directory from variable set by external parameter

Tags: shell, rm

I would like to run a shell script *test_shell.sh* to delete a directory defined by a parameter set in another file *test_config.txt*.

**test_config.txt:**

```
var = testdir
```

**test_shell.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

vardel=$(grep var test_config.txt | cut -d ' ' -f3)
echo $vardel
rm -rf $var
```

The variables are set correctly, but the directory is not deleted. No warning is printed. What causes this?

Comment: the config file might have CRLF line endings

Comment: I thought about this. Indeed I am using WinSCP to edit the file which is located on the unix side. I have changed the line endings to Unix, but the problem persists (see update to the question).

Comment: @Fravadona: Somehow, only the second directory `testdir_rel` (located in the same directory as the shell script) is deleted, `testdir_abs` is for whatever reason not deleted.

Comment: try replacing the `echo`s with `printf '%q\n' "$abspathdel" "$relpathdel"` and see what's really in those variables

Comment: @Fravadona: Found the issue. In the actual script, it was really the line ending issue. In the minimal example, in the absolute path (which in my case was not /home, but a different path), I had some typo I had not noticed. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Happy you found a solution. Consider putting all this as an answer and concluding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Fravadona, this was related to Windows line endings (CR LF) when read on a unix system.